# Why Oracle Apex send Web Service request from Oracle Database and not from Apex Listener?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have configured Application Express 4.2.2.00.11, using Oracle Apex Listener 2.0.3, connected to an apex instance on a different Server. It is playing well except when i try to consume a web  service (Amazon S3, Google Geocode, etc.), i noticed that need Oracle Database instance to have internet connection. It is surprising because i was expected only to allow Listener container server connect to internet.

So i want know if is there any way to consume Web Services in Oracle Apex without expose database server to internet (connecting Apex Listener only to internet).

Comment: APEX Listener is a web-server only. It listen inbound connections only. All your code executes in database, so all outbound requests made from database.

Comment: Thank you @NoGotnu it's clear for me now. But how the second part if is there any way consume web service (like maybe JavaScript interface). Some known workaround?

Comment: Oracle APEX is a part of database. Generally APEX is a several packages and tables in some schema. So, you have two ways: 1). Open connection for databse to internet 2). Choose another architecture (JAVA app, PHP app, NODE.JS app) on the server that has connection to the internet.

Comment: well, you could probably achieve this in some part by employing a proxy server to serve as an intermediary between your database and the web. Don't forget that all of apex runs within the db. Any call made from the db is done from the current user/schema, and thus calls to resources outside of the db will originate from the db, not the webserver.